# using acf_form in front, how to display the product fields and metadata of woocommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a form in front-end by [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to submit products by user as a vendor and save the submitted form as a new product.

this is the code I am using it:

```
$options = array(
'post_id' => 'new_post',
'post_title' => true,
'post_content' => true,
'new_post'      => array(
  'post_type'       => 'product',
  'post_status'     => 'draft'
 ),
'field_groups' => [$my_field_group_id_created_in_acf],
'form' => true,
 'return' => '%post_url%',
'html_submit_button'    => '<input type="submit" value="%s" />',
'updated_message' => 'Product Created',
'submit_value' => 'Submit Product'
```

);

acf_form($options);

The output form has title field, content editor, and ACF group fields, but the price field, or other meta data of product(such as regulare price, category, tags and etc) not appears in the form!
How can I display other own product fields or other custom metadata (not related by ACF) in the form for submitting?

Comment: What fields are in your field groups?

Comment: Some fields, such as text input, they appear in the front-end. 
I would like to display the default price field of product, or the stock field.

Comment: If you're writing to WooCommerce product fields, you want to make your acf field `_regular_price` for example.

Comment: So I should `_regular_price` in ACF fields and there is not way to use the default woocommerce product fields. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks It works by adding new acf field like `_regular_price`

Comment: ACF Fields are just postmeta. For WC, many of the field names are prefixed with the `_`